# How can I get the most common value on a SQL array?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working with a food delivery dataset which contains the user_id and states where my clients have a registered address. Let's assume that the states that appers more often are the ones where the client lives and the others are places they visited or lived for a short period of time.

```
>>> ADDRESSES
  USER_ID  | STATE                            |
_______________________________________________
0   100    |   ["AL", "AL", "AL"]             |
1   101    |   ["LA", "LA", "MI"]             |
2   102    |   ["NY", "NY", "KY", "NY", "NY"] |
3   103    |   ["DE", "DE", "CO", "CO", "DE"] |
4   104    |   ["CA"]                         |
5   105    |   ["FL", "GA", "LA", "LA"]       |
6   106    |   ["ID", "ID", "ID", "DE"]       |
7   107    |   ["TX", "TX", "VT"]             |
8   108    |   ["RI"]                         |
9   109    |   ["TN", "TN", "OK", "VA"]       |
```

That being said, how can I get the most common state for each client so I can get the result bellow?

```
>>> ADDRESSES
  USER_ID  | STATE |
____________________
0   100    |   AL  |
1   101    |   LA  |
2   102    |   NY  |
3   103    |   DE  |
4   104    |   CA  |
5   105    |   LA  |
6   106    |   ID  |
7   107    |   TX  |
8   108    |   RI  |
9   109    |   TN  |
```

Comment: Please only tag the database you're actually running your query against.

Comment: and what the data type of `STATE` column? ARRAY or STRING?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider (BigQuery) below approach (assuming that state column is array of strings)

```
select user_id, 
  ( select st from t.state st
    group by st order by count(1) desc 
    limit 1 ) state
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: which tool did you use to create the sample data?

Comment: I just used sample data presented in the question. it is in text so was easy to do. and i used nothing for this besides [BigQuery console](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery) . meantime my usual/regular IDE for BigQuery is [Goliath](https://potens.io/products/#goliath) and [Magnus](https://potens.io/products/#magnus) for workflows orchestration, scheduling, etc.  you can see more at https://potensio.zendesk.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are no arrays in standard SQL.  There might be such a thing in the DBMS you're using, but not in general.

What I see in

```
0   100    |   ["AL", "AL", "AL"]             |
```

is 2 columns: an integer, and a string.  I'm guessing that's not really it; I'm guessing the tool you're using represents an "array" in your DBMS using Python syntax: `[]` to indicate an array, and `""` to indicate strings.  So an array 3 strings.  But that's just a guess because you don't say.

The standard answer to your question is prefixed by *don't do that*.  Since before SQL was invented, First Normal Form (1NF) proscribed *repeating groups* as a datatype.  That is to say, the table is not in 1NF.  To answer the question you asked with SQL as she is spoke, you first need to eliminate the repeating groups.

How?  For that row, you need something like this:

```
0   100    |   1  | ["AL"             |
0   100    |   2  | ["AL"             |
0   100    |   3  | ["AL"             |
```

How you get there, I don't know.  It depends on what you actually have, and what your DBMS offers.  But, once you're there, the query almost writes itself:

```
select X.user_id, min(X.state) as state
from (
    select user_id, state, count(state) as N
    from table_1nf
    group by user_id, state ) as X
join 
    select user_id, max(N) as N
    from (
        select user_id, state, count(state) as N
        from table_1nf
       group by user_id, state ) as foo
) as T
on X.user_id = T.user_id and X.N = T.N
group by X.user_id
```

That query ensures that, in the event of a tie, you get only the first state having the highest count.

Comment: "*There are no arrays in standard SQL*" - yes there are.

Comment: Thanks, I stand corrected.  The SQL 2003 standard apparently added an ARRAY type. It's a string on steroids: you can operate on and compare parts of it.  What you can't do is very much with it as a set, most especially any kind of GROUP BY.  So the *make it a column* answer remains afaict the right one.

Comment: You are right. Using an array is almost always a bad choice. But it's more than just a "string on steroids". An array can be defined based on any data type (integer, date, ...). You can turn an array into a rows using unnest

Comment: Interesting about unnest, thanks.  If anyone asked me, I'd say use ARRAY only if the thing really is a mathematical array that will be used as one, for e.g. linear algebra.  If you're just using it to hold a repeating group, you're violating 1NF, a pretty basic error.